# Spring Data JPA Subquery with Criteria API

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create a dynamic query with Specification with two entities which have bidirectional relation. The entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table("SUPPLIERS")
public class Supplier implements Serializable {

    @Id
    Column("ID")
    private Long id;

    @Id
    Column("COMPANY_ID")
    private Long companyId;
}


@Entity
@Table("EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "FIRM_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "FIRM_COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName = "COMPANY_ID")
    })
    private Supplier supplier;
}
```

When I want to select employees based on their supplier,

```
return new Specification<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Employee> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

        Long[] supplierCodes = {1L, 2L};

        Subquery<Supplier> supplierBasicSubquery = query.subquery(Supplier.class);
        Root<Supplier> supplierBasicRoot = supplierBasicSubquery.from(Supplier.class);
        Join<Employee, Supplier> sqTfV = root.join("supplier", JoinType.INNER);

        supplierBasicSubquery.select(sqTfV).where(sqTfV.<Long>get("id").in(supplierCodes));


        return root.<Supplier>get("supplier").in(supplierBasicSubquery);
    }
};
```

When its executed, it generates SQL like:

```
SELECT ....
   FROM EMPLOYEES E
       INNER JOIN ....
   WHERE (E.FIRM_ID, E.FIRM_COMPANY_ID) in 
      (SELECT (s.ID, s.COMPANY_ID) FROM SUPPLIERS WHERE SUPPLIER.ID in (1, 2))
```

As you can see, the inner select columns are surrounded by parenthesis which causes Oracle to throw exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

How can I fix this issue, any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.